# List private events of a github repository?

Tags: events, github-api

I want to get private events of a github repo. The documentation for github api v3 suggests this end point `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/events` but I am not seeing any events using that. I am afraid if it has something to do with github apps, because there is an information icon on the endpoint which on hover says enabled for github apps. I am not sure what that exactly means, though I have read about github apps. Does that imply that only github apps are eligible for this endpoint and if yes then how other apps can access the private repo events ?